# Image marque animation in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

In my project I want marquee n number of images. I have tried but not succeeded. when I give the Duration in same it all images are combined and moving.

My XAML -

```
 <Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Canvas.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard >
                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="img1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)">
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="514" Duration="0:0:20" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard >
                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="img2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)">
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="514" Duration="0:0:20" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard >
                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="img3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)">
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="514" Duration="0:0:20" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Canvas.Triggers>
            <Image Name="img1" Source="/Images/01.jpg" Height="180" Width="120"  />
            <Image Name="img2" Source="/Images/02.jpg" Height="180" Width="120"  />
            <Image Name="img3" Source="/Images/03.jpg" Height="180" Width="120"  />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

My Model is -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the following link and apply it in your case.

http://weblogs.asp.net/razan/archive/2009/10/01/creating-marquee-scrolling-text-in-wpf.aspx

Update 1:

Modified your code as follows seems to meet your requirement

```
<Grid>
            <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Canvas.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard >
                            <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="panel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)">
                                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="514" Duration="0:0:20" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>                   
                </Canvas.Triggers>
                <StackPanel x:Name="panel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Name="img1" Source="/Images/01.jpg" Height="180" Width="120"  />
                    <Image Name="img2" Source="/Images/02.jpg" Height="180" Width="120"  />
                    <Image Name="img3" Source="/Images/03.jpg" Height="180" Width="120"  />
                </StackPanel>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: your link give the solution for marquee. But I have n number of images, how can i move in serial like a train.

Comment: the image marquee not continue. i wana image3 before image1 while morqueeing. its not happen. see the step2 nad step3